# How to use zipped file for editor input

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, gzip

I have a running code that opens editor by taking **FileStoreInput** as editorInput(*FileStore is created using a remote file*). 
Now I want to open editor from a gzipped file(**java.util.zip** package is used for gzipping) which is on remote server.
**Constraint is that no file should be created on the local system.**

I tried **StorageInput** put it fails while opening editor.

Comment: You should show the code you have that isn't working and describe in more detail how it fails.

Comment: This project might have some code and/or ideas that you can leverage: http://sourceforge.net/projects/zipeditor/